# Why is jQuery selector only applied to first item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html form has optional items to display as follows:

```
<span class="Optional Command1 Command2">
   <label for="elem1">Elem 1:</label><input type="text" id="elem1" /><br />
</span>
<span class="Optional Command1 Command3">
    <label for="elem2">Elem 2:</label><input type="text" id="elem2" /><br />
</span>
```

An html select element is used to select Command1, Command2 or Command3 which corresponds to the class for the above html elements.

When the select change event happens, it calls the following function:

```
function showOptional(commandName) {
   $('.Optional').hide();  // clear out optional inputs
   $('.Optional').filter('.' + commandName).show();  // show relvant inputs
}
```

However for Command1, which is included in the class for both elem1 and elem2 above, only the first input element will be displayed, but I thought the jQuery selector would apply both.

In other words, for the above html the showOptional('Command1') Javascript function only displays the first span with Command1, but not the second span with Command1. Why not both?

Comment: Your code should show both. There's some other issue if it isn't.

Comment: I don't see anything that would stop that working, and in fact it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qH2KF/. Is there some other code somewhere that could be removing the classes?

Comment: They're hidden by `.hide()` in your function. Note that if you change the code in the fiddle to pass "Command2" or "Command3" to the function then only one of the spans is shown, and if you pass some other string none are shown, so the code you've shown definitely works and the problem must be elsewhere. If you want to see it working when they start hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/qH2KF/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function showOptional(commandName) {
   $('.Optional').hide();  // clear out optional inputsinputs
   $('.Optional.' + commandName).show();  // show relvant 
}

showOptional('Command1');​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sYXuM/1/

---

However, your original approach works for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/sYXuM/2/

---

I just ran a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/jq-filter) and the following code is faster than your original approach and my suggestion above:

```
function showOptional(commandName) {
   $('.Optional').hide().filter('.' + commandName).show();
}
```

Comment: Also, I like how you concatenated the two classes. I initially tried that, but I though a space was supposed to be in between the two classes so it did not work for me (it's been a long time since I last used JS & jQuery, guess I forgot alot)!

Comment: @JHarri you'd put a space in there if the element with the second class is supposed to be a descendant of the element with the first class. To test for both classes on the same element, you use the no-space syntax.